# Create Python dataframe conditionally

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a dataframe based on if col1 and col2 are empty, but col3 has information.
I'm currently using np vectorize, but this creates the dataframe every line versus just a single time.

Here's my code:

```
def import_check(Col1,Col2, Col3):
    
    if Col1=='' and Col2=='' and  Col3 !='':
        print('being imported')
             
        list=pd.read_csv('mycsv.csv', low_memory=False)
        list.columns=list.columns.str.strip()

        print('List imported')
        
    else:
        
        list= None
       
    return(list)
```

The function is called like so:

```
list=np.vectorize(import_check)(df['calories'], df['duration'],df['size'])
```

For example if I have 10 lines that match the data will import 10 times.
I would like to get my list to read in only once.
Is this possible?

If there's anymore information I need to add please let me know

EDIT: Here's an example

```
data = {
  "calories": ['420', '', ''],
  "duration": ['50', '', '']
  "size": ['30','10','10']

}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

If you used this data the list dataframe would be imported twice because col1 and 2 are empty but col3 exists with data.

I'd like it to only import once.

Comment: the question is not really clear to me, can you give some examples of input data and what you want as an output

Comment: Sure! I've edited a small example at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

you don't want to vectorize your function. If you do that, it'll run for each row in your series. Rather, what you want is to change this condition

```
if Col1=='' and Col2=='' and  Col3 !='':
```

Rather than looking at whether the row is zero you could do something like

```
# this checks to see if you have any non '' in the column
if (df[col1] != '').sum() > 0 and ...
```